# remove space at actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i want change button menu to back when goto a fragment.
I used this code:

```
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.back50);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

but when run button have space at left. [image]

[image]

Comment: are you passing transparent image there in blank space

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to remove that space

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    View homeIcon = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
        // Hides the View (and so the icon)
        if (homeIcon != null)
            ((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! While this code block might answer the question  you should try to improve your answer by adding relevant explanation see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer